# take the mathematical expression from the string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have bunch of strings as follows:

```
0 + (1/4 - sqrt(5)/4)*i + 1/2*j + (1/4 + sqrt(5)/4)*k
1 + 0*i + 0*j + 0*k
1/2 + 1/2*i + 1/2*j + 1/2*k
```

I want to extract numbers and mathematical expressions from these strings.

I wrote a function for it.  It worked for second and third line but does not work for the first line:
Here is my function:

```
import math
import re
import numpy as np
matrices_of_icos = []
from fractions import Fraction
pattern = r"[-+]?(?:\d+(?:/\d+)?)|(?:sqrt\(\d+\))"
#pattern = r"[-+]?(?:\d+(?:/\d+)?)|(?:sqrt\(\d+\))|\((?:[-+]?(?:\d+(?:/\d+)?))?(?:[+-]\s*sqrt\(\d+\))?\)"
for i in saving_icos:
    numbers = []
    string_ico = str(i)
    print(string_ico)
    # Find all matches of the pattern in the string
    matches = re.findall(pattern, string_ico)
   
    for match in matches:
        #with_par = re.findall(r'\(([\S]*?)\)(?=\s|$)', match)
        #print(with_par)
        if "/" in match:
        # Fraction case: convert string to Fraction object
            number = float(Fraction(match))
            numbers.append(number)
        elif "sqrt" in match:
        # Square root case: extract the number inside sqrt and calculate square root
             num = int(re.search(r"\d+", match).group())          
             number = math.sqrt(num)
             numbers.append(number)
        else:
        # Integer or decimal case: convert string to float
             number = float(match)
             numbers.append(number)
    print(numbers)
```

The output of the code for the first line is as follows:
[0.0, 0.25, 2.23606797749979, 4.0, -0.25, 2.23606797749979, 4.0, 0.5]
How can I generalize my code for finding the first line correctly? It should come as [0,0.8,0.3,0.5]
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. You need a parser, not a regular expression. Chomsky 1956.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be done solely with regex, you would first need to match the parenthesis so their inner value can be calculated first.

Then if you wish to evaluate e.g. `(1/4 - sqrt(5)/4)` it using your own code, would require that first `sqrt(5)` is evaluated, then `1/4` and `sqrt(5)/4`, after which the final value can be calculated.

If you know your icos always follow the format above, this might work:

```
from math import sqrt
import re

for icos in saving_icos:
    parts = []
    open_parenths = 0
    part = ""
    for char in icos:
        if char == "(":
            open_parenths += 1
        if char == ")":
            open_parenths -= 1

        if char == "+" and open_parenths == 0:
            parts.append(part.strip())
            part = ""
        else:
            part += char

    parts.append(part.strip())

    values = []
    for part in parts:
        part = re.sub(r"\*[ijk]", "", part)
        values.append(eval(part))

    print(values)
```

It first extracts the parts, keeping track of how many opening and/or closing parenthesis it has passed, and then uses pythons built-in `eval` to get the value.
Note that it uses

```
from math import sqrt
```

as the evaluation of `sqrt(5)` is evaluated as python code, and uses the `sqrt()` function.